# how to show selected value in alertDialog

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

Hi all in my application I am using AlertDialog, in this I have 3 values. User select one value and selected value is stored in sharepreference. I want to use this saved value and by default want to set this value as selected in radio button. Following is my code.

```
private void getFontSize()
{

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    String selectedSize = sharedPreferences.getString("fontSize", "Medium");


    final CharSequence[] items = {" Small "," Medium "," Large "};

    ArrayList<CharSequence> arrItems=new ArrayList<CharSequence>(Arrays.asList(items));
    int prevSelectedIndex = arrItems.indexOf(selectedSize);


    // Creating and Building the Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select The Font Size");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, prevSelectedIndex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


            switch(item)
            {
                case 0:
                    Constants.fontSize = "Small";
                    editor.putString("fontSize",Constants.fontSize);
                    editor.commit();

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Constants.fontSize = "Normal";
                    editor.putString("fontSize",Constants.fontSize);
                    editor.commit();

                    break;
                case 2:
                    Constants.fontSize = "Large";
                    editor.putString("fontSize",Constants.fontSize);
                    editor.commit();
                    break;


            }
            levelDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    levelDialog = builder.create();
    levelDialog.show();
}
```

Here if saved value is null then I am using "Medium" as selectedSize value. How I can show selected radio button, so when user run this application again then it shows radio button of Medium (or other if user selected other) as selected.
Any suggestion will be appreciatd, Thanks in advance

[image].

Comment: Where is your radio button code?

Comment: @Fahim sorry its not radio button. But Alert with three value and you can choose only one value at a time like radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass  `selectedSize` as second parameter to `setSingleChoiceItems` method as:

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> arrItems=new ArrayList<CharSequence>(Arrays.asList(items));
int prevSelectedIndex = arrItems.indexOf(selectedSize);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, prevSelectedIndex,...
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, But still it is not working. I had updated my code in question.

Comment: @PPD: what value you are getting in `selectedSize` and `prevSelectedIndex` ?

Comment: I am getting selectedSize:Normal  and prevSelectedIndex:-1

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
String selectedSize = sharedPreferences.getString("fontSize", "Medium");

        final CharSequence[] items =
        {
        "Small", "Medium", "Large"
        };

        int selectedIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if(items[i].equals(selectedSize))
            {
                selectedIndex=i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Creating and Building the Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select The Font Size");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, selectedIndex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
            {

                switch (item)
                {
                ...
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog levelDialog = builder.create();
        levelDialog.show();
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I also missed this! in items[] we have extra space in all words and what we are saving in cache are without space. See edits.